# Insertar en tabla con foreign key en nodejs y mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente código con *mysql* y *nodejs*... Es para insertar una publicacion. El problema es que no estaría logrando insertar la ultima query...

```
router.post("/game/publish", function(req,res,next){
  const id = "SELECT id from `info` where id = '"+req.body.tittle+"'"
  const query = "INSERT INTO `content`(`id`,`title_content`, `gameplay`, `link1`, `link2`, `link3`) VALUES ('','"+req.body.tittle+"','"+req.body.gameplay+"', '"+req.body.link1+"', '"+req.body.link2+"', '"+req.body.link3+"');";
  const query2 = "INSERT INTO `info`(`id`,`title_info`,`descripcion`,`req`, `instrucciones`)  VALUES  ('', '"+req.body.tittle+"','"+req.body.desc+"','"+req.body.requisitos+"','"+req.body.inst+"');";
  db.query(query + query2 + id  , function(err, results){
    if(err) throw err;
    const query3 = "INSERT INTO `juegos` (`id`, `id_info`, `id_content`, `titulo`, `img`, `genero1`, `genero2`, `genero3`) VALUES ('',' "+results[0].insertId+"-['"+req.body.tittle+"']',' "+results[0].insertId+"-['"+req.body.tittle+"']','"+req.body.tittle+"','img/"+req.body.image+"','"+req.body.genre1+"','"+req.body.genre2+"','"+req.body.genre3+"')";
    db.query(query3, function(err, results){
      res.send(results)
    }) 
    })
  })
```

`query` y `query2` se ejecutan normalmente, en cambio la `query3` da el siguiente error...

```
 sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'klkl']','97-['klkl']','klkl','img/doom_eternal.jpg','','','')' at line 1",   
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO `juegos` (`id`, `id_info`, `id_content`, `titulo`, `img`, `genero1`, `genero2`, `genero3`) VALUES ('','97-['test']','97-['test']','klkl','img/doom_eternal.jpg','','','')"
```

Comment: Si te fijas en el error verás que tienes problemas escapando algunos caracteres, pues repites las comillas simples dentro de algunos campos: `VALUES ('','97-['test']','97-['test']','klkl', ...`

Comment: @masterguru a ver.. intentare solucionar eso!..